FDA Drug Name differentiation ("Tall Man Lettering")
I am a software developer working on a platform where we are currently using data from OpenFDA, specifically the NDC directory, for a web application in which users search for one or more medications. The way we have it set up is to pull the entire JSON dataset periodically, and ETL it into our own format/database for retrieval.
We have had a request to display the FDA-recommended "Tall Man Lettering" format for drugs which have generic names that are similar to other drugs. However, as far as I can tell, neither the data in the OpenFDA NDC, Labeling, nor Drugs@FDA have a reference to this recommended lettering.
Is there anywhere where this recommended chart is published in such a way that is easily consumed programmatically?

We at openFDA do not have that information.
However, it appears you can request a TML download here: https://home.ecri.org/blogs/ismp-resources/look-alike-drug-names-with-recommended-tall-man-mixed-case-letters
